# URI Error with Ruby when trying to run an application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

so for some reason my Ruby encounter this error when I try to create a new application on Windows 10:

```
rails aborted!
URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?): C:\\Ruby\\bin;C:\\sqlite;
C:/Users/Lies/demo42/Rakefile:6:in `<main>' <internal:C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:38:in `require'
\<internal:C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb\>:38:in `require' bin/rails:4:in `\<main\>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
rails  turbo:install stimulus:install
rails aborted!
URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?): C:\\Ruby\\bin;C:\\sqlite;
C:/Users/Lies/demo42/Rakefile:6:in `<main>' <internal:C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:38:in `require'
\<internal:C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb\>:38:in `require' bin/rails:4:in `\<main\>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I've searched everywhere on Google and so far I've try reinstalling twice, changing the path varible to C:\ruby and adding it to path and DATABASE variable.

My ruby, rails is on the latest version.

So far running "rails new demo --minimal" is the only one that work in helping me creating the application but when I try to run the server it show this: [localhost:3000 output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMNKO.png)

Has anyone encountered this and figure out how to fix? I asked my professor, and it also picked his brain trying to figure out.

**database.yml**

```
# SQLite. Versions 3.8.0 and up are supported. 
# gem install sqlite3 
# Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile 
# gem "sqlite3" 
#
default: &default 
  adapter: sqlite3 
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %> 
  timeout: 5000
development: 
  <<: *default 
  database: db/development.sqlite3 
# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and 
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake". 
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production. 
test: 
  <<: *default 
  database: db/test.sqlite3 
production: 
  <<: *default 
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

Edit: for future reader:
Here is the DATABASE_URL_ env variable with two value of "C:\sqlite" and "C:\Ruby\bin"
I encounter the problem again later on, but manage to fix it again by editing the 'Path' env varible to only containing ruby and git value.

Comment: What does your `config/database.yml` look like?

Comment: Where this string is defined? How is your `database.yml` looks? Do you have `DATABASE_URL` env variable?

Comment: @mechnicov Hi, I do have DATABASE_URL_ env variable with two value of  "C:\sqlite" and "C:\Ruby\bin" 
I'll include database.yml below

Comment: @spickermann Here is the database.yml:

# SQLite. Versions 3.8.0 and up are supported.
#   gem install sqlite3
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem "sqlite3"
#
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000

Comment: ...

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3
# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have `DATABASE_URL` env variable, Rails use it as priority database configuration and try to parse it. But its value is invalid. That's why you have error

Instead of this use `config/database.yml` to store database settings and delete `DATABASE_URL` env variable

[Read more](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#connection-preference)

Comment: Thank you for your help! Turns out the problem was DATABASE_URL, I just deleted it, reopened cmd and it worked!

Comment: @Lies glad to help you. Please edit the question and add information about `DATABASE_URL` value you had directly to the question body. Such way your question can be helpful and understandable for others